# How to join two tables based on ID and get information

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

Hello I need some help regarding SQL Query.

Table A

```
ID      Name     Type 
--------------------- 
1        abc     BC 
--------------------- 
2        def     SD  
---------------------
3        ghi     BC  
----------------------
```

Table B (BC_ID and SD_ID are Foreign keys of Table 'B' referencing the Primary key 'ID' of Table 'A')

```
ID     BC_ID    SD_ID
---------------------  
1        1        2  
--------------------- 
2        3        2  
---------------------
```

I am using VB.Net datagrid view to print the Table B details. I need to print 2 more columns in datagridview which specifies the Name of the corresponding BC_ID and SD_ID.
How do I write a SQL query which can get the 'Name' of the Corresponding ID's from the database and print in datagridview...

Expected Output in datagridview:

```
ID    BC_Name   SD_Name
---------------------   
1       abc        def  
--------------------- 
2       ghi        def   
---------------------
```

I dont want to have separate BC_Name and SD_Name columns in the table B..I just need to join the two tables and get the name in a single query..Is it possible? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I am able to get the Name linking either BC_ID OR SD_ID with the ID of Table A. But I do not get the idea as to how to get the Name linking both BC_ID and SD_ID in same query

Comment: What SQL engine are you using: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, ...?

Comment: I am using SQL Server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join TableA twice with different alias names.

Try this:

```
SELECT B.ID,ISNULL(A1.NAME,'') as BC_NAME,ISNULL(A2.NAME,'') as SD_NAME
FROM TableB B LEFT JOIN
TableA A1 ON A1.ID=B.BC_ID LEFT JOIN
TableA A2 ON A2.ID=B.SD_ID
```

Result:

```
ID  BC_NAME  SD_NAME
1   abc      def
2   ghi      def
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0543/1).

Comment: The above query works....Thank you... But since the ID field of Table A is PK and it doesnt allow null.. But I have FKs which allows null.. I have an option where in the datagridview i can delete an associated BC_ID or SD_ID which sets the field to null... But when the above query is executed again it doesnt show those records which has BC_ID and SD_Id set to null.. In this case I would prefer to see an empty column with no BC_Name or SD_Name rather than seeing no record...

Comment: @Shiva: Replace `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`. Edited my answer.